# CSS - position: sticky stops at the bottom of the original screen height

Tags: html, css

I have a setup similar to:

```
<body>
    <div class="non-moving-header">
    </div>
    <div class="floating-header">
    </div>
    <div>
        Some vertically expanding content...
    </div>
</body>
```

with

```
body, html
{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.floating-header
{
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 0;
    position: sticky;
}
```

The issue is that the sticky element works fine, until it reaches the position of the original bottom of the viewport, where it stops as if it had reached the end of its parent element. If I manually set the body/html height property to something like 1500 it tracks as expected all of the way down the document. Is there a way to get position:sticky to properly track to an auto-sizing parent element?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

You need to add **overflow: scroll** to your CSS for your full page wrapper/container div, then your targeted sticky element should scroll the full length of your web page and not get stuck when you exit your original view port.

Comment: @jhpratt the attached section is what helped me figure out why the sticky nav stopped sticking when it hit the bottom of the original viewport. The remaining article was informative but the attached section should help anyone trying to understand how the sticky element works. I'm trying to find the link though.